# Como passar valores de controles entre janelas diferentes?

Tags: c#, winforms

e estou com uma dúvida aqui sobre a programação em C#, que estou na dúvida de como fazer.

Bom, primeiramente estou com um programa C# de Windows Form Application, nele criei 2 forms, sendo o form1 sendo o principal, onde tem um menu que seria para escolher como se fosse um script, no geral o projeto por completo seria para logar um usuário e senha numa determinada URL da internet.

Mas enfim é isso, e no form1, coloquei 4 radiobutton, sendo que nesses radiobutton cada um deverá conter uma matricula e senha.
E também cheguei a colocar um botão para iniciar tal script.
E quando fosse clicado em tal botão para iniciar ele chama o form2, que nele foi colocado o componente WebBrowser.

Até citado acima está ok.
Minha duvida seria a seguinte.
Queria saber algum método de eu conseguir retornar o valor da radiobutton para o outro form ao clicar no botão iniciar.
Na parte do radiobutton seria um código no exemplo abaixo, contendo os dois valores e pegando a opção que estiver marcada, porém queria saber como eu iria fazer o retorno desse valor para ir em outro form que seria o utilizado no componente WebBrowser

```
if (radioButton0.Checked)
{
    rb_matricula = 8020137;   //André Venicios
    rb_senha     = "senha0";
}
else if (radioButton1.Checked)
{
    rb_matricula = 7011288;   //Clériston Morais Santos
    rb_senha     = "senha1";
}
else if (radioButton2.Checked)
{
    rb_matricula = 5010940;   //Daniel Ribeiro Bandeira
    rb_senha     = "senha2";
}
```

O meu botão iniciar script só coloquei o mesmo redirecionando ao form2

```
private void btn_Iniciar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frmBrowser navegador = new frmBrowser();
    navegador.ShowDialog();
}
```

Bom agora indo para o form2, ele irá iniciar o componente WebBrowser já no seguinte link

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("https://172.16.0.47/pessoal/");
```

Feito isso, eu coloquei o mesmo para pegar uns certos dados da URL do site existente.
E preencher esse campo, com o valor selecionado na radiobutton do form1, que seria este campo.

```
bool pWeb = false;

private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if(!pWeb)
    {
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("usu_login").InnerText = "7011288";
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("usu_senha").InnerText = "senha1";
    }
    pWeb = true;
}
```

E a dúvida final seria de pegar o valor retornado do radiobutton, e colocar no lugar onde está a matricula e a senha. após o InnerText, arranjando outro método para passar ele, após que pega o elemento pelo ID e o insere.

Se alguém puder me ajudar nessa dúvida minha, ficarei muito grato, pois travei neste modo como irei passar ele e qual método poderia utilizar para colocar no lugar do InnerText.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pode passar as informações necessárias ao segundo `form` através do constructor e guardar essas informações em `private fields` para depois poderem ser utilizadas pelo método `webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted`:

```
private readonly string _username;
private readonly string _password;

public frmBrowser(string username, string password)
{
    _username = username;
    _password = password
}

private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if(!pWeb)
    {
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("usu_login").InnerText = _username;
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("usu_senha").InnerText = _password;
    }

    pWeb = true;
 }
```

Desta forma, no evento de clique do botão basta construir o segundo `form`:

```
frmBrowser navegador = new frmBrowser(rb_matricula, rb_senha);
```

EDIT:

Relativamente aos `radiobuttons`, assumindo que entendi bem, isto é, ter um método que encontre o `radiobutton` selecionado e retorne a matricula e a senha.

A minha solução para o problema seria:

```
private class InformacaoUtilizador
{
    public string Matricula { get; private set; }

    public string Senha { get; private set; }

    public InformacaoUtilizador(string matricula, string senha)
    {
        Matricula = matricula;
        Senha = senha;
    }
}
```

Assim com a classe pode criar uma nova instância para cada para de matricula/senha e atribuir essa instância à propriedade `Tag` do `radiobutton` (no constructor do Form ou no evento `Load`):

```
radioButton0.Tag = new InformacaoUtilizador("matricula", "senha");
radioButton1.Tag = new InformacaoUtilizador("matricula", "senha");
radioButton2.Tag = new InformacaoUtilizador("matricula", "senha");
```

De seguida, cria um método que encontra o `radiobutton` selecionado e retorna o objecto que estiver na `Tag` do `radiobutton` (caso não esteja nenhum `radiobutton` selecionado, retorna `null`):

```
private InformacaoUtilizador SelecionarInformacao()
{
    RadioButton res = Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().FirstOrDefault(r => r.Checked);

    if (res == null)
        return null;

    return res.Tag as InformacaoUtilizador;
}
```

Por fim, dentro do evento `Click` do botão:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var info = SelecionarInformacao();
    if (info == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Tem de seleccionar um botão.");
        return;
    }

    frmBrowser navegador = new frmBrowser(info.Matricula, info.Senha);
    frmBrowser.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: Certo, a questão do radiobutton eu poderia fazer desse jeito, criando uma nova função, porem como seria o retorno dela para ir ao botão do click, sendo que ele só iria pegar o retorno do valor do radiobutton que estiver com checked?

Comment: Consegui, realmente agora deu certo, muito obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma de acessar os dados do `form` principal no secundário é setando o `form` principal como parent do secundário. Para isso podemos utilizar o construtor do `form` secundário passando como argumento o `form` principal.
Fica mais ou menos dessa forma, na linha aonde tu declara e instancia o segundo form:

```
private void btn_Iniciar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frmBrowser navegador = new frmBrowser(this);
    navegador.ShowDialog();
}
```

Dessa forma é possível acessar os controles do `form` principal pelo objeto `parent`. Exemplo:

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if(!pWeb)
    {
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("usu_login").InnerText = parent.rb_matricula;
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("usu_senha").InnerText = parent.rb_senha;
    }

    pWeb = true;
 }
```